# PHP & JS - Connection, Error Messages and Redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, authentication

I pretty much finish my job, everything works except redirecting and now I will show it to you.

So, I have a website, set up with HTML, CSS, PHP, MySqli and in the end (How weird it shouldn't sound) I planned to add some JS.

I need to finish up my Login form, everything seems to work correctly.

HTML + CSS + JS Code:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html lang="en">
     <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Home</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <style>
        #form-mes1{
            background-color: rgb(255, 232, 232);
            border: 1px solid red;
            color: red;
            display: none;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            padding: 15px 25px;
            max-width: 450px;
        }
    </style>
        <body>
            <header>
                <div class="container1">
                        <img src="img/header.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="container3">    
                <form class="login-form2" method="post" action="login.php">
                    <ul id="form-mes1">
                        <li>Generic Error #1</li>
                    </ul>

                    <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="logemail" class="input">

                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="logpassword" class="input">

                    <button type="submit" id="btn_submit" name="sButton" class="btn2">LOGIN</button>


                </form>
            </div>  

            <script>
                const container3 = {
                    email: document.getElementByID('email'),
                    password: document.getElementByID('password'),
                    submit: document.getElementByID('btn_submit'),
                    messages: document.getElementByID('form-mes1')
                };

                container3.submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    request.onload = () => {
                        let responseObject = null;

                        try{
                            responseObject = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                        }catch(e){
                            console.error('Cannot Pass JSON');
                        }

                        if(responseObject){
                            handleResponse(responseObject);
                        }
                    };

                    const requestData = `email=${container3.email.value}&password=${container3.password.value}`;

                    request.open('post', 'login.php');
                    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urldecoded');
                    request.send(requestData);
                });

                function handleResponse(responseObject){
                    if(responseObject.ok){
                        location.href = 'dashboard.html';
                    }else{
                        while(form.messages.firstChild){
                            form.messages.removeChild(container3.messages.firstChild);
                        }

                        responseObject.messages.forEach((message) => {
                            const li = document.createElement('li');
                            li.textContent = message;
                            container3.messages.appendChild(li);
                        });

                        container3.messages.style.display = "block";
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </body>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

$ok = true;
$messages = array();

if(isset($_POST['sButton'])){

    if(empty($_POST['logemail']) or empty($_POST['logpassword'])){
        $ok = false;
        $messages[] = "Values Can't Be Empty";
    }elseif($ok){

        $email = $_POST['logemail'];
        $password = $_POST['logpassword'];

        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");

        $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, "car_accs");

        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Mail = '$email' AND Password = '$password'");

        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($rows == 1){
            $ok = true;
            $messages[] = "Successful Log In";
        }else{
            $ok = false;
            $messages[] = "Failed To Log In";
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
}
echo json_encode(
    array(
        'ok' => $ok,
        'messages' => $messages
    )
);

 ?>
```

Everything works, if I miss out mail or password I get message:

[image]

If I write incorrect data I get the same type message:

{"ok":false,"messages":["Failed To Log In"]}

And If I log in successfully, this message:

{"ok":true,"messages":["Successful Log In"]}

But the idea is that if I log in successfully, I need to be redirected as you see in the JS code, if not than I have a display box which shows errors in a red box.

[image]

Something goes wrong and JS code almost doesn't work and I don't understand why, any help will be just amazing.

Comment: check the developer tools to see if the request went to php as expected if so then your issue is with JS

Comment: It doesn't send I guess, everything works perfectly, except I physically can't use JS right now because nothing calls it and I don't understand why

Comment: You've added an event listener to something that doesn't emit events, the generic object called container3.  You would probably want to add that event listener to the form.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in the contact between the JS and HTML.

First problem was about DIV that I created, which couldn't use addEventListener property, as well as with the inputs, I used both ID and Class and it was a mistake and program just didn't continue to work it was on break.

After changing both DIV and inputs to only ID option (Needed to write CSS right in to the HTML file) I wrote the JS code once again and everything went perfectly.

Here is the code HTML + CSS + JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Home</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <style>
        .form{
            background-color: white;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 40px;
            clear: both;
            height: 550px;
            width: 450px;
            margin: 100px auto;
            color: #24E7B9;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        #form-messages{
            background-color: rgb(255, 232, 232);
            border: 1px solid red;
            color: red;
            display: none;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            padding: 15px 25px;
            max-width: 450px;
        }
        #mail,
        #pass{
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
            border: 2px solid #24E7B9;
            color: black;
            font-size: 16px;
            outline: none;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
        }
        #btn-submit{
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #24E7B9;
            height: 60px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 60px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
        <body>
            <header>
                <div class="container1">
                        <img src="img/header.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="form">
                <ul id="form-messages"></ul>

                <label for="mail">E-Mail</label>
                <input type="mail" id="mail">

                <label for="pass">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="pass">

                <button type="submit" id="btn-submit">Login</button>

            </div>



            <script>
                const form = {
                    mail: document.getElementById('mail'),
                    pass: document.getElementById('pass'),
                    submit: document.getElementById('btn-submit'),
                    messages: document.getElementById('form-messages')
                };

                form.submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    request.onload = () => {
                        let responseObject = null;

                        try{
                            responseObject = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                        }catch(e){
                            console.error('Could Not Pass JSON');
                        }

                        if(responseObject){
                            handleResponse(responseObject);
                        }
                    };

                    const requestData = `mail=${form.mail.value}&pass=${form.pass.value}`;

                    request.open('post', 'login.php');
                    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    request.send(requestData);
                });

                function handleResponse(responseObject){
                    if(responseObject.ok){
                        location.href = 'dashboard.html';
                    }else{
                        while(form.messages.firstChild){
                            form.messages.removeChild(form.messages.firstChild);
                        }
                        responseObject.messages.forEach((message) => {
                            const li = document.createElement('li');

                            li.textContent = message;
                            form.messages.appendChild(li);
                        });

                        form.messages.style.display = "block";
                    }
                }

            </script>
        </body>
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

$mail = isset($_POST['mail']) ? $_POST['mail'] : '';
$pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : ''; 

$ok = true;
$messages = array();


if(!isset($mail) OR empty($mail)){
    $ok = false;
    $messages[] = 'Mail Cannot Be Empty';
}

if(!isset($pass) OR empty($pass)){
    $ok = false;
    $messages[] = 'Password Cannot Be Empty';
}   


if($ok){
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");

    $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, "car_accs");

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Mail = '$mail' AND Password = '$pass'");

    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($rows == 1){
            $ok = true;
            $messages[] = "Successful Log In";
        }else{
            $ok = false;
            $messages[] = "Failed To Log In";
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);

}
   echo json_encode(
    array(
        'ok' => $ok,
        'messages' => $messages
    )
);

?>
```

Redirecting and connection problems are solved. Thank you everybody.